# Hemisphere volume plot

Tags: plotting, geometry, animation

I am trying to show an animation of the hemisphere volume. I tried to start with some radius and rotate it, to get an area of a circle. Then, I will stack up the circle in z-axis to make a hemisphere. The plot which I did, only shows the surface of hemisphere and not in the right order.

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[{r*Cos[theta], r*Sin[theta], 
   Sqrt[1^2 - r^2]}, {theta, 0, t}, {r, 0, p}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {t, 0.1, 2*Pi}, {p, 0.1, 
  1}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another version of @cvgmt's answer, but going in the opposite direction.

```
Manipulate[
  With[
    {upperRadius = Sqrt[1 - height^2]},
    RevolutionPlot3D[{
      {r, Sqrt[1 - r^2]},  
      {Rescale[r, {upperRadius, 1}], 0}, 
      {Rescale[r, {upperRadius, 1}, {0, upperRadius}], height}}, 
      {r, upperRadius, 1}, 
      PlotRange -> 1, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]],
  {height, .01, 1}]
```

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**

Reply to the comment.

```
(* $Version 13.0 and above *)
Animate[
 CSGRegion["Intersection", {Ball[], Cuboid[{-1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, h}]}, 
  PlotRange -> 1, BaseStyle -> {Darker@Cyan}], {h, .001, 1.1}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]

**Original**

Do you mean `RevolutionPlot3D` of such outlines?

```
Show[With[{h = .3}, 
  ParametricPlot[{{t, h}, {t, Sqrt[1 - t^2]}}, {t, 0, Sqrt[1 - h^2]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[8], Opacity[.2]]]],
 With[{h = .8}, 
  ParametricPlot[{{t, h}, {t, Sqrt[1 - t^2]}}, {t, 0, Sqrt[1 - h^2]}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]]]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 RevolutionPlot3D[{{t, h}, {t, Sqrt[1 - t^2]}}, {t, 0, Sqrt[1 - h^2]},
   Lighting -> {PointLight[Green, Scaled[{2, -2, 2}]], 
    PointLight[Yellow, Scaled[{2, 2, -2}]]}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotRange -> 1, 
  ViewPoint -> {1.15, -3.12, -0.61}], {h, 0, .99}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice use of `RevolutionPlot3D`. I was trying to do it with `ParametricPlot3D` but your approach is much nicer!!!

Comment: Thank you. This is very nice. Actually I was trying to do in opposite direction.  To start with a circle. And when I increase the z from o to r, it will make a hemisphere. This is pretty close , so I can edit to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but based on the phrase "stack up the circle in z-axis to make a hemisphere" I think what you actually want are cylinders.

Maybe you want something like this:

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[
    {EdgeForm[], 
     Cylinder[
       Partition[Array[{0, 0, #} &, sliceCount, {0, 1}], 2, 1], 
       Array[Sqrt[1 - #^2] &, 1 + sliceCount, {0, 1}][[2 ;; -2]]]}],
  {sliceCount, 2, 100, 1}]
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I was trying to start with a circle instead of a cylinder. And when I increase the z-axis the stacked circle gets smaller and becomes hemisphere when z=radius. This is close though.